# mongodb kerberos authentication

Tags: mongodb, kerberos

I am following the documentation in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-with-kerberos-authentication/ and I get the following error when running this step.

```
use $external
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "application/reporting@EXAMPLE.NET",
     roles: [ { role: "read", db: "records" } ]
   }
)
```

First of all it doesn't recognize db.createUser(), I changed it to db.addUser(). (I am using ver 2.4) I changed the user value to my account.

However I get the following error.

Mon Jun 23 17:28:14.519 couldn't add user: cannot insert into reserved $ collection at src/mongo/shell/db.js:128

Instead of doing use $external, I changed the addUser to include usersource attribute and then I get the error

Mon Jun 23 17:30:49.876 couldn't add user: system.users entry must have either a 'pwd' field or a 'userSource' field, but not both at src/mongo/shell/db.js:128

Any help regarding this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2.4 you have to follow the [instructions here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-with-kerberos-authentication/), that is, something like this:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("records")
db.addUser( {
              "user": "application/reporting@EXAMPLE.NET",
              "roles": [ "read" ],
              "userSource": "$external"
            } )
```

You also need to be running the Enterprise version of 2.4 or Kerberos authentication will not work.

Comment: How do I check if I am running the enterprise version? I downloaded from the site.

Comment: When I run it now I get the following error.db.addUser( { user: "application/

Comment: When I run it now I get the following error.
db = db.getSiblingDB("records")
db.addUser( { user: "xxx@yyy.com, 
              usersource: "$external", 
              roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "Maps" } ] } )

Tue Jun 24 11:39:16.962 couldn't add user: system.users entry must have either a 'pwd' field or a 'userSource' field, but not both at src/mongo/shell/db.js:128

I tried using application/xxx@yyy.com instead and still get the same error.

Comment: I get the same error even after installing enterprise version mongodb-linux-x86_64-subscription-suse11-2.4.10.tgz (I got this from the web after searching for enterprise mongodb)

Comment: you have a typo - case sensitivity matters - it's userSource, not usersource

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos support is only available for MongoDB enterprise. You can download from MongoDB website.

As for the user permission, you'll need to use 2.4-based tutorial since the permission schema have changed since then. The one you are using is for 2.6.